# <div>s with relative width inside container <div> - how to overflow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Situation**

- I have a set of `<div>` elements inside a container `<div>`.
- The width of the inner `<div>` are set to relative sizes in percentage.
- Sometimes the sum of the widths of the inner divs are over 100%.

**How it is**

What happens currently, is that the inner divs are squashed in a way to fit the container.

```
<div id="container" style="float:left; display:flex; width: 500px">
    <div style="background-color: black; width: 90%">test</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 90%">test</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgvhfb9e/2/

As you can see, the red one is exactly the same size as the black one.

**What I want**

What I need is that the last div is simply cut off at the end of the container.
Therefore, the red one should only be 10% while the black one is 90%.

Comment: Why not just switch the CSS for the second one to 10% instead of 90%?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than shown :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `flex-shrink: 0` on the child elements
- `overflow: hidden` on the parent

This prevents child elements from being shrunk to fit within the parent, and prevents your "10% visible" child element from being visible outside the bounds of the parent element.

```html
<div id="container" style="float:left; display:flex; width: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="background-color: black; width: 90%; flex-shrink: 0;">test</div>
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 90%; flex-shrink: 0;">test</div>
</div>
```

And here's a variant using the `flex` shorthand property to set `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` properties all at once.

```html
<div id="container" style="float:left; display:flex; width: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="background-color: black; width: 90%; flex: 1 0 auto;">test</div>
  <div style="background-color: red; width: 90%; flex: 1 0 auto;">test</div>
</div>
```